# Cloud Functions for Firebase error handling

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm wondering what's the right way to write the node.js code when I have chained promises and I need to update the realtime database if something goes wrong?

Here is the code:

```js
export const testErrorHandling = functions.database
      .ref('/workqueue/{pushId}/something').onWrite(event => {

  // Exit when the data is deleted.
  if (!event.data.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  //This is the retry count, give up if more than 5 times have been retried.
  const data = event.data.val()
  if (data.count >= 5) {
    return
  }

  return event.data.ref.root.child(data.fulluri).once('value').then(snapshot => {
    //Process all, if ok, delete the work queue entry
    return event.data.ref.remove()  
  }).catch(exception => {
    console.log('Error!: ' + exception)

    //Log error, increase retry count by one an write to that 
    //location to trigger a retry

    //Is the line below OK?
    //return event.data.ref.child('count').set(data.count + 1)
  })

})
```

I would guess this is common requirement in many cases, but couldn't find an example as all examples seem just to write to console.error and be done. (Which in real world is seldom enough.)

Comment: You should only catch errors when you can actually handle them in your code. So what do you expect to go wrong that triggers the catch? How do you want to handle it?

Comment: Btw: There is currently no way to force a retry in Cloud Functions, but it will likely be added in a future version.

Comment: We're creating a PDF on AWS Lambda, writing it to Cloud Storage, verfiying it got written correctly and can be opened, send an email using postmark containing the written PDF as an attachment and updating data accordingly. 

We could probably set retries to all https calls etc, but the amount of work and testing is a bit too much. It's a lot easier to write idempodent code (which it has to be regardless how retries are implemented) and just retry the whole lot. 

So generally we're seeing a service go down, result in a temporary error code, or end up with a corrupted write to cloud storage

Comment: But this code only catches a failure to write to the database and tries to signal that with another write to the database. The most likely reason for such a write failure is a network connection problem. The chances of the second write succeeding in that case are quite small.

Comment: Yes, this is only example. There's about ten calls to various systems between the read from firebase and the catch using chained thens. If any call goes south, we need to requeue and try again. If Firebase does not work, the chain is not started and no harm is done. As the code is idempodent, we can try as many times as we'd like. The only reason to not retry is that there's something wrong with the data or our code, in which case it ends up being on our human work queue after couple of cron initiated emergency runs that are timed for entries that linger around.

Comment: OK, that sounds like a (complex but) cool use-case. I would probably not rely on Functions retries here (even if they would exist), but would write a "lastTriedTimestamp" for the task and trigger a new function invocation based on that.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen! That's a very pragmatic KISS approach, I like it a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Developer on Cloud Functions for Firebase]
Your idea is pretty clever. It will work many times but won't catch lower-level issues like the database being unavailable or a timeout in your app (though that could be fixed with a Promise.race that enqueues a retry).

We're working on adding retries to the core product. Since you've brought up the issue, I'd love to solicit some customer input. As a developer, what features do you need/expect in a retry policy? What do you feel is a sane default and how would you expect to override those defaults?

Comment: We're actually OK with app being offline etc, as we're planning to have a checkup cron job, that touches any workqueue entries that are older than x, resulting in retriggering the database trigger, where x is 25 times the estimated worst case execution time. This way we'll catch any "dropped" workqueue entries and be eventually consistent, where majority of items are handled really quickly.

Comment: As for the wishlist, here it goes: I'd love to see per function retry policy that gradyally backs off and gives up if retry count is over limit (default) 5. Backoff algorithm probably exponential so couple first should be done quickly and the rest relatively slowly with greater interval between. I don't know if it's too late to add automatic retry if there is uncatched exception, but there should be a way to opt-in to manually ack everything is OK. This is a requirement that should be implemented also to Pub/Sub trigger, as currently it is too unreliable :/

Comment: And thanks for the great work! CF for Firebase is evolving to be an amazing product!

Comment: Oh, and now that I'm writing, I'd also love to see declarative security ala database / storage security for https functions (defaulting to everything open?). That would be awesome!